# Why is mac OS X killing python?

Tags: python, macos

I can no longer run python on my mac.  Upgraded to mac OS X 10.11.4 Beta and now if I run python it gets killed.

$python

Killed: 9

the system log shows:

taskgated[396]: killed pid 954 because its code signature is invalid (error -67030)

Comment: Well, that's why it's called Beta! Report it back and they might revive it! It's killing the process, and the only reason I can think of is that running it clashes with something they may have implemented / changed!

Comment: Mac believes python is venomous and unhealthy to system.

Comment: I should add that this python is my own install in a virtual environment.  Its been running fine for 2 years, just this install of 10.11.4 beta killed it.  The system python in /usr/bin runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be fixed in TODAY's beta release:  15E39d